# Using multiple images in layout android

Tags: android, imageview

In my application I want to create a layout as shown below I am confused about what size of images should I keep in my resource folder.
[image]

Comment: Where is the link ?

Answer (score 0):

A 1.5 inch wide mdpi display is about 240px wide but considering variable sizes for android devices I'd say to fill your screen an image 400px wide should be safe to use on mdpi devices. Scale height according to the required aspect ratio and scale both dimensions for different densities(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) accordingly.